# How I can change PayPal IPN 'custom' field in woocommerce?

Tags: custom-field, customization, plugins, paypal

I use Woocommerce plugin. All works great, but I need add to PayPal IPN 'custom' field only 1 word instead "order_id" that writes at 'custom' field now.

I trying edit this file:
...woocommerce/classes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php
[here you can see code](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/woocommerce/woocommerce/classes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php)

[here screenshot of code that maybe needs to change](http://i.piccy.info/i7/02273fdf57c10ed93c482a32d70670ce/4-57-1154/53374038/custom_field_800.jpg)

Need to change script that send "order_id" to PayPal on script that send my word to PayPal. That's all.

I believe it's easy to do. Please help.
Appreciate any answers. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

You almost gave the answer yourself :o)

replace

```
'custom' => serialize( array( $order_id, $order->order_key ) ),
```

with

```
'custom' => 'yourword',
```

and you're done!

Comment: Mr. Ewout, please help me again.
I need to do the same thing - to add a "custom" parameter to all payments from my website. Only difference is now I use Wordpress 4.5.3 and I can't find even the word "custom" there.
here the screenshot, where it probably should be: http://i.piccy.info/i9/759c50ab52808a6dc4d89684e40e8e30/1467032457/308628/1046856/paym.jpg

Am I right? Help me please